# Creating a Skew AngleY from a Skew Factor for a Rhomboid in XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, math, geometry, skew

I'm not sure if this is possible, but basically I have two degrees that will change the width/size and skew of an image. In a tranformation matrix (`<Matrix3DProjection/>`), it works like this:

```
M11:cos(x)   M12:sin(y)*sin(x)   M11:0
M21:0        M22:cos(y)          M23:0
M31:0        M32:0               M33:1
```

So if I have `X = 30°` and `Y=40°`, my matrix is:

```
M11:0.866    M12:0.321           M11:0
M21:0        M22:0.766           M23:0
M31:0        M32:0               M33:1
```

So [image: normal] becomes [image: 30x40]

What I'd like to use instead is a `<TransformGroup/>` but can't quite figure out the `<SkewTransform AngleY="???"/>` portion. The `<ScaleTransform/>` seems easy enough by using **M11** and **M22** values above in `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` like `<ScaleTransform ScaleX=".866" ScaleY=".766"/>`.

But I can't figure out the `AngleY` portion of `<SkewTransform/>` from an `M12` value of **0.321**. I know that from doinking around with this manually, a value of `AngleY="20.3"` seems very accurate. But I can't figure out the math behind this.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Reflector on the SkewTransform class to find out the math.  It calls [Matrix.Skew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.skew.aspx), which uses the matrix:

```
1.0           tan(skewY)    0.0
tax(skewX)    1.0           0.0
```

Since you want `tan(skewY) * 0.766 = 0.321`, you get `skewY = atan(0.321 / 0.766) = 22.7366108 degrees`.  Or, going back to your original numbers, `skewY = atan(sin(y) * sin(x) / cos(y)) = atan(tan(y) * sin(x))`, which yields `atan(tan(40 degrees) * sin(30 degrees)) = 22.7604763 degrees`.

Comment: Oh man, I had a lot of high hopes for this. Unfortunately, a value of 22.76 doesn't work for AngleY to show the same shear as `M12=0.321`. I've tried on other calculations as well and it doesn't work for them either. Could it also be related to something else, like the width/height of my rectangle?

Comment: @Otaku: Ah, I was doing the Skew followed by the Scale, but you were doing the Scale followed by the Skew.  That should just reverse X and Y in my formula, yielding `atan(tan(30 degrees) * sin(40 degrees)) = 20.3605749 degrees`.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to read between the lines a little you want to avoid using the `Projection` property and use to the `RenderTransform` instead?

If so rather than trying to work out how to use `ScaleTransform` and `SkewTransform` just use the `MatrixTransform` in the `RenderTransform`.

```
 <MatrixTransform Matrix=".866, .321, 0, .766, 0, 0" />
```

OR

```
 <MatrixTransform M11="0.866" M12="0.321", M22="0.766" />
```